# Angular2 routing without component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-directives

I want to listen to **NavigationStart** event and judge if its `url` attribute is `/logout`.
If so, the router should stop firing successive events, such as **RoutesRecognized**, **GuardsCheckStart**, **ChildActivationStart**, etc., when my listener detects correct **NavigationStart** event.
Otherwise the router should keep on routing.

I don't want to use a component, 'cause I ain't gonna display any `/logout` view.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.scss']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
  ) {
    router.events.filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart).subscribe(
      (event: NavigationStart) => {
        if (event.url == '/logout') {
          this.logout();
          // TODO stop firing successive events
        }
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() { }

  logout() {
    // TODO logout operations
  }

}
```

Comment: You have to redirect your user somewhere though, because otherwise, he'd stay on a view for authenticated users. Can't you redirect the user to the Sign In view? It's not really clear what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a route guard. When route matches 'logout', the 'YourGuard' will be used to activate or not the route. If the guards returns true, it will be redirected to 'users/sign_in' (just an example). If not, inside the YourGuard you can redirect to other path or do something else.

```
{ path: 'logout', canActivate: [ YourGuard ], redirectTo: 'users/sign_in' }
```

You don't need to 'listen' to the route events.
Read more about guards [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards).

Comment: What if I want to do something when logging out? For example: set or change a variable?

Comment: You can do this in the canActivate() method from the guard.

Comment: I tried, but `YourGuard.canActivate()` is not invoked. Do you know why?

Comment: [CanActivate] gurd is not triggering without a component. there is a ticket, https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18605   workaround => {path: 'logout', children: [], canActivate: [LogoutGurd]},

Answer (score 0):

Use the LoginComponent instead of redirectoTo:

```
  {
    path: 'logout',
    canActivate: [YourGuard],
    component: TheLoginComponent,
  }
```

Now in **YourGuard** you can remove the user from the local storage or something like that...